# Print sections in text file using awk and shell variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a text file, `materials.txt`, with a large number of material definitions similar to this:

```
*FILESTART
line_a
line_b
line_c
*MAT_PLASTIC
         1 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
*MAT_STEEL
         2 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
*MAT_WOOD
         3 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
*MAT_ALUMINUM
         4 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
*MAT_RUBBER
         5 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
*MAT_GOLD
         6 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7 
*SOMETHING_ELSE
line_x
line_y
line_z
*END
```

Each section starts with a header, beginning with an asterisk (*) and ends at next asterisk.

I would like to print only the sections with the metals (i.e. *MAT_STEEL,
*MAT_ALUMINUM and *MAT_GOLD) with all properties of each of those materials.
The desired output is this:

```
         2 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
         4 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
         6 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
```

I can print *one* of the materials, e.g. *MAT_STEEL, with this:

```
awk  '/^\*/ { f=0 } /^\*MAT_STEEL$/ { f=1 ; next } f' materials.txt
```

Result:

```
         2 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
```

Since the list of metals is actually much longer in my real file, I would
like to create a list of them and loop through it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
METALS="MAT_STEEL  MAT_ALUMINUM  MAT_GOLD  MAT_SOMETHING1  MAT_SOMETHING2  MAT_SOMETHING3"

for M in $METALS ; do
    awk  -v mtrl="$M" '/^\*/ { f=0 } "/^\*" mtrl "$/" { f=1; next } f' materials.txt
done
```

No matter how I use the "mtrl" variable, I cannot get the output right.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

With a single awk call:

```bsh
awk '
    BEGIN {
        metal["*MAT_STEEL"] = 1
        metal["*MAT_ALUMINUM"] = 1
        metal["*MAT_GOLD"] = 1
        metal["*MAT_SOMETHING1"] = 1
        metal["*MAT_SOMETHING2"] = 1
        metal["*MAT_SOMETHING3"] = 1
    }
    $1 ~ /^[*]/ {p = 0}
    $1 in metal {p = 1; next}
    p
' materials.txt
```

```
         2 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
         4 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
         6 property1 property2 property3
 property4 property5 property6 property7
```

Comment: This is a great workaround! Thank you Glenn!